# MouseX Value Changes When Cursor Is Still

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

Here is my code:

```
public function update()
    {
        //making the character follow the mouse
        if(mouseX > (x + 25))
        { //if the mouse is to the right of mcMain
            x += mainSpeed;//move mcMain to the right
        }
        else if (mouseX < (x - 25))
        {//same thing with the left side
            x -= mainSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            trace(x + " and " + mouseX);
            x = mouseX;//if it's close enough, then make it the same x  value
        }
    }
```

For some unknown reason, mouseX and this object's c change values even when cursor is still (meaning the object flickers)

Here's the trace, when I leave cursor still:

```
84 and 80
80 and 84
84 and 80
80 and 84
84 and 80
80 and 84
84 and 80
```

mouseX isn't being changed by me (and can't be since it's read-only), there isn't any other code in this object since I've only just started with this project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like your mouseX is based on the clip owning the 'x' property you are setting. When you constantly set x to mouseX, this will change the cursor's position relative to the clip. This is why it oscillates between the two values.

fix: try using the parent clip to get the mouse position, then change the child clip's position as needed. ie: _parent.mouseX instead of mouseX